# Show scrollbar onmousehover [javascript]?

Tags: javascript

I need to show scrollbar on mouse hover on a div similar to facebook or gmail. is there any free JS library for that?

Answer (score 2):

if the div has an overflow property set to hidden you can set it to scroll on hover.

```
div.onmouseover =function () {
    this.style.overflow = "scroll";
}
```

it can also be done using css only.

```
#divId {
   overflow:hidden;
   height: 100px;
}
#divId:hover {
   overflow:scroll
}
```